# Как создать столбец на основе двух столбцов из двух разных DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, big-data

```
data = pd.read_table(io.StringIO('''
geo_id       TimeStamp 
1            1380052543                
3            1375703582      
34           1374479873         
3            1374479892 '''), sep='\s+')

geo = pd.read_table(io.StringIO('''
id     TZ_OFFSET
3      10800
34     0
1      7200 '''), sep='\s+')
```

Суть задачи в том, что я хочу изменить столбец "время", добавив к нему данные из каталога со смещением временной метки, и соответственно найти в каталоге значение подходящее под `id` клиента из первой таблицы.

Короче, нужно создать новый столбец на основе двух столбцов из двух разных DataFrame, причем эти столбцы связаны, у них `geo_id` из фрейма `data` и `id` из фрейма `geo` совпадают.

Ожидаемый результат:

```
geo_id       TimeStamp    TZ_OFFSET
1            1380052543     7200          
3            1375703582     10800 
34           1374479873     0   
3           1374479892      10800
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Спасибо, я отредактировала вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Векторизированное решение:**

`mp` - вспомогательный `Pandas.Series`, который будет использоваться для "маппинга":

```
mp = geo.assign(offset=pd.to_timedelta(geo.TZ_OFFSET.astype(str)+'S')).set_index('id')['offset']


data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['TimeStamp'], unit='s') + data['geo_id'].map(mp)
data['TS'] = (pd.to_datetime(data['TimeStamp'], unit='s') + 
              data['geo_id'].map(mp)
             ).astype('int64') // 10**9
```

PS столбец `date` был создан для наглядности. Судя по выходному DF из вопроса, в реальном скрипте он не понадобится

**Результат:**

```
In [29]: data
Out[29]:
   geo_id   TimeStamp                date          TS
0       1  1380052543 2013-09-24 21:55:43  1380059743
1       3  1375703582 2013-08-05 14:53:02  1375714382
2      34  1374479873 2013-07-22 07:57:53  1374479873
3       3  1374479892 2013-07-22 10:58:12  1374490692
```

**Проверка:**

```
In [30]: data.eval("Offset = TS - TimeStamp")
Out[30]:
   geo_id   TimeStamp                date          TS  Offset
0       1  1380052543 2013-09-24 21:55:43  1380059743    7200
1       3  1375703582 2013-08-05 14:53:02  1375714382   10800
2      34  1374479873 2013-07-22 07:57:53  1374479873       0
3       3  1374479892 2013-07-22 10:58:12  1374490692   10800
```

---

**UPDATE:** если в выходном DF требуется получить дату/время со смещением в формате *UNIX epoch / timestamp*, то гораздо проще будет просто прибавить `TZ_OFFSET` (смещение в секундах) к `TimeStamp` (число секунд прошедших с `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`):

```
In [40]: data = (data.merge(geo, left_on='geo_id', right_on='id')
                     .eval("TS = TimeStamp + TZ_OFFSET"))

In [41]: data
Out[41]:
   geo_id   TimeStamp  id  TZ_OFFSET          TS
0       1  1380052543   1       7200  1380059743
1       3  1375703582   3      10800  1375714382
2       3  1374479892   3      10800  1374490692
3      34  1374479873  34          0  1374479873
```

Comment: Cпасибо, буду разбираться! :)

Comment: @MashaMaximova, [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Вот с merge я сама хотела сделать)

Comment: Я проверила 2 варианта: с merge и c map, и второй оказался работающим, а вот насчет merge: он заменил одни значения geo_id, на другие там, где это не должно было произойти. Такой результат связан со спецификой работы merge - это функция, которая сравнивает значения попарно, а не подбирает пары ключ - значение.